# Amazon EC2 Free Tier when will "COMPUTE" exceeds its limitation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS and trying to learn its concepts. This one is really confusing to me about the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/).

This says 750 hours of free COMPUTE each month, (24 hours * 31 days = 744 hours).

My question is when will I end up overusing it? As I don't want to pay any money in first year.

Comment: You will not, it is free

Comment: @JunedAhsan In which case I may end up paying more during "Free Tier" for 1st year ?

Comment: In no case as far as I know for Free tier, you will pay only after the first year

Comment: Documentation may not be clearly understandable to all engineers who are new to AWS, so IMHO there is no need to downvote and discourage genuine query from new engineer. Also this is not asked by anyone earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full description is:

> 750 hours per month of Linux, RHEL, or SLES t2.micro instance usage

This can be used as one instance running all the time, or two instances running for 375 hours or 10 instances running for 75 hours, etc. It is applied as a billing discount, giving **the first 750 hours at no charge**.

**If you run *ONE* t2.micro instance, then there will be no charge for the instance during the first year.**

However, there might be some **associated charges** such as Amazon EBS Volumes, Elastic IP addresses (if not attached to a running instance), data transfer, snapshots and T2 Unlimited. There is a free tier for each of these, but charges will apply if the free tier is exceeded.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer and not down voting for a valid query. Documentation may not be clearly understandable to all engineers